# gdb: displaying char array as big endian shorts

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, endianness

Let's assume I have an array like

```
char foo[] = { 0, 1, 1, 0 };
```

In `gdb`, on an x86 machine, if I say

```
p (short[2])*foo
```

I get

```
{256, 1}
```

this is, two bytes are interpreted as a `short` in little endian order.

Is there a convenient way (e.g. a macro) to make `gdb` display a bytearray as big endian shorts (or whatever type) instead?

Comment: Check the [link](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_130.html) form more information for setting endian-ness for target programs. However setting endian-ness could display different `GDB` output values making debugged program unaffected. Source: [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848507/need-info-on-set-endian-on-solaris-machine).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`set endian big`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Byte-Order.html#index-set-endian-1176). Use `set endian auto` to switch back to automatic endianess selection.

```
(gdb) p (short[2])*foo
$1 = {256, 1}
(gdb) set endian big
The target is assumed to be big endian
(gdb) p (short[2])*foo
$2 = {1, 256}
(gdb) set endian auto
The target endianness is set automatically (currently little endian)
(gdb) p (short[2])*foo
$3 = {256, 1}
(gdb)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work.  While I can say
`p /d (short[2])*foo` just fine, after emitting `set endian big`
gdb tells me `No symbol "foo" in current context.`  This is gdb 7.5.1, BTW.

Comment: I didn't make up the output above, it was from an actual `gdb` session with the same code you provided. I am using `gdb 7.5.91`.

Comment: Well, my real-use code is more complicated, namely a local pointer to an allocated memory area, and somehow it seems that gdb is no longer able to interpret this pointer correctly, thus reporting that it can't find symbol `foo`.  This is the very reason that I'm asking for a macro or the like (since I've tried the endian settings before writing the question here).

Comment: If the print works before setting endian, try doing `p (void *)&foo[0]` to get the pointer value. Then after setting the endianess, cast the address itself: `p /d (short[2])0xSOMETHNG`.

Comment: Alas, whatever I try, it doesn't work.  Using your suggestion, even with `set endian big`, I get exactly the same values as with `set endian little`.  Maybe it's really a problem with my gdb version, since you get working results.  I will eventually do an update to something more recent and retry.  Thanks for you help!